# Inverse transform sampling for piecewise function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447035/inverse-transform-method-with-piecewise-pdf

I have the same question as the one above, which was wasn't answered. I am doing inverse transform sampling with the following pdf:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 2 - x, & 1 < x \leq 2 \end{cases}$$

which gives the cdf

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^2}{2}, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} - 1, & 1 < x \leq 2\end{cases}$$

I know I take the case of $$\frac{x^2}{2} =u$$
and get
$$x = \sqrt{2u}, $$

And then for the other case:

$$2x - \frac{x^2}{2} - 1=u $$

$$ - \frac{x^2}{2}+2x  - 1-u =0$$

$$\quad \quad x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4(-0.5)(-u-1)}}{-1}.$$

$$\quad \quad x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 +2(-u-1)}}{-1}.$$

$$\quad \quad x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2 -2u}}{-1}.$$

$$\quad \quad x = \frac{2 \mp \sqrt{2 -2u}}{1}.$$

I'm unclear what the next step is.

Comment: The range of $u$ is $[0, 1]$. You should divide it into $[0, 1/2)$ and $[1/2, 1]$ accordingly. Then, if $0 \le u < 1/2$, $F^{-1}(u) = \inf\{x : ~ F(x) \ge u\} = \sqrt{2u}$, and if $1/2 \le u \le 1$, $F^{-1}(u) = 2 - \sqrt{2 - 2u}$.